# Tooltipster and Jquery Validator issue when used with forms inside animated collapse div drawers

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, tooltipster

Any help would be greatly appreciated please.

I have a page full of "drawers" which operate like an accordion. Couldn't use Jquery UI accordion for various reasons. So instead im using Animated Collapse 2.4 from dynamic drive. Each of the drawer divs contain unique forms. On those forms I am using Jquery Validator and tooltipster to display the validation errors.

The problem I have is that when a draw is closed before validation success, the tooltipsters don't disappear completely they hang around where the form was, and if you scroll the page or move around at all they jump to the top left hand side of the screen half shown! So they sort of hide but don't fully. It's as if they need positioning just a few more dozen pixels up and left.

Because I have multiple div drawers containing forms, sometimes it's necessary to switch to another drawer when completing one particular draw's form to reference other data. So sometimes I need users to be able to close a drawer without fully completing each form and come back to it later.

Any ideas please?

You need to include the js scripts from Dynamic Drive for the animatedcollapse.js - available at [Link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm)

Also you need to include the jquery.tooltipster.js and css files which can be downloaded at [Link](https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster)

HTML:

```
<head>
<script src="js/animatedcollapse.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tooltipster.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
    <p><b>Example 1 (individual):</b>

    </p>
<a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.toggle('cust')"></a>  <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.show('cust')">Slide Down</a> || <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.hide('cust')">Slide Up</a>

    <div id="cust" style="width: 800px; background: #FFFFCC; display:none">
        <form id="custForm" name="custForm" method="post">
             <h4>Enter your customer details</h4>

            <p>Title:
                <BR />
                <select name="titleBox" id="titleBox">
                    <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                    <option value="Mis">Ms</option>
                    <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
                    <option value="Dr">Sir</option>
                </select>
            </p>Firstname:
            <BR>
            <input name="firstnameBox" type="text" id="firstnameBox" size="40" onkeyup="" onblur="" minlength="1" required />
            <BR />Surname:
            <BR>
            <input name="surnameBox" type="text" id="surnameBox" size="40" onkeyup=""  minlength="2" required />
            <BR />Home tel:
            <BR />
            <input name="hometelBox" type="text" class="phoneUK" id="hometelBox" size="40" onkeyup=""  required />
            <BR />Mobile:
            <BR />
            <input name="mobileBox" type="text" id="mobileBox" size="40" minlength="7" onkeyup=""  required/>
            <BR />Work tel:
            <BR />
            <input name="worktelBox" type="text" id="worktelBox" size="40" minlength="7" onkeyup=""  required/>
            <BR />Email:
            <BR />
            <input name="emailBox" type="text" class="EMAIL" id="emailBox" size="40" />
            <BR />
            <BR />
            <BR />
<strong><em>Address Manual Entry</em></strong>

            <BR/>
            <BR />House Name/Flat number:
            <BR />
            <input name="man_housenmBox" onkeyup=""  type="text" id="man_housenmBox" size="40" />
            <BR />House Number:
            <BR />
            <input name="man_housenoBox" onkeyup=""  type="text" id="man_housenoBox" size="40" />
            <BR />Street Name 1:
            <BR />
            <input name="man_street1Box" onkeyup=""  type="text" id="man_street1Box" size="40" minlength="4" required/>
            <BR />Street Name 2:
            <BR />
            <input name="man_street2Box" onkeyup="" size="40" />
            <BR />Town/City:
            <BR />
            <input name="man_townBox" type="text" id="man_townBox" size="40" minlength="4" />
            <BR />County:
            <BR />
            <input name="man_countyBox" onkeyup="" type="text" id="man_countyBox" size="40" minlength="4" />
            <BR />Postal Code:
            <BR />
            <input name="man_postcodeBox"  class="postcodeUK" type="text" id="man_postcodeBox" minlength="4" />
            <BR />
            <BR />
            <P align="center">
                <button id="sub" value="Trigger validation" type="submit"><span class="ui-button-text">Trigger Valdation</span>

                </button>
            </P>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

And JS:

```
animatedcollapse.addDiv('cust');


animatedcollapse.ontoggle = function ($, divobj, state) {};

animatedcollapse.init();


$(document).ready(function () {
    // initialize tooltipster on text input elements
    $('#custForm input[type="text"]').tooltipster({
        theme: 'tooltipster-shadow',
        positionTracker: 'true',
        trigger: 'custom',
        onlyOne: false,
        position: 'right',
        animation: 'fall',
         positionTrackerCallback: function(){
             this.hide();}


    });
});



jQuery.validator.messages.required = "";

$.validator.addMethod("EMAIL", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,6}$/i.test(value);
}, "Email Address is invalid: Please enter a valid email address.");


jQuery.validator.addMethod('phoneUK', function (phone_number, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
    //phone_number.match(/^(((\+44)? ?(\(0\))? ?)|(0))( ?[0-9\s]{3,4}){3}$/);
    phone_number.match(/^\(?(?:(?:0(?:0|11)\)?[\s-]?\(?|\+)44\)?[\s-]?\(?(?:0\)?[\s-]?\(?)?|0)(?:\d{2}\)?[\s-]?\d{4}[\s-]?\d{4}|\d{3}\)?[\s-]?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3,4}|\d{4}\)?[\s-]?(?:\d{5}|\d{3}[\s-]?\d{3})|\d{5}\)?[\s-]?\d{4,5}|8(?:00[\s-]?11[\s-]?11|45[\s-]?46[\s-]?4\d))(?:(?:[\s-]?(?:x|ext\.?\s?|\#)\d+)?)$/);
}, 'Please specify a valid UK phone number');

jQuery.validator.addMethod("postcodeUK", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]? [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}/i.test(value);
}, "Please specify a valid UK Postcode - with a space between the first and second parts - e.g. RG1 2BT");




var validator = $("#custForm").validate({

    messages: {
        firstnameBox: "Please enter a first name or initial (min 1 character).",
        surnameBox: "Please enter a last name (min 2 characters).",
        hometelBox: "Please enter the end user's home UK landline number (must be a valid UK number).",
        worktelBox: "Please enter a work telephone number.",
        mobileBox: "Please enter a mobile phone number.",
        emailBox: "Please enter a valid email address.",
        man_street1Box: "Please enter a street name",
        man_townBox: "Please enter a Town.",
        man_countyBox: "Please enter a County.",
        man_postcodeBox: "Please enter a valid UK postal code, with a space between the first and second parts - e.g. RG1 2BT."
    },


    rules: {
        hometelBox: {
            required: true

        },
        emailBox: {
            required: false,
            email: true
        }

    },



     errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        var lastError = $(element).data('lastError'),
            newError = $(error).text();

        $(element).data('lastError', newError);

        $(element).tooltipster('show');

        if (newError !== '' && newError !== lastError) {
            $(element).tooltipster('content', newError);
         $(element).tooltipster('show');
        }
    },
    success: function (label, element) {
        $(element).tooltipster('hide');

    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {
        // do other things for a valid form

    }
});
```

Comment: So show the relevant code!  You're having problems with drawers, but you show no code that has anything to do with the drawers.  That includes the HTML markup.

Comment: Sparky many thanks for your response. I wasn't sure whether to paste all the code because sometimes I get criticised for posting too much!! SO - I have created a small example page here [link](http://jnbworks.co.uk/demozone/test/test.html)   So if you trigger validation on the form by clicking the save button (doesn't do a save in this demo it just causes validation on the inputs) the validation via tooltipster works. With the validation tooltips open now click slide up to close the drawer. Then scroll around the screen - the tooltips all go to the top left

Comment: Jsfiddle here  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/k5w3tfsd/)

Comment: Unfortunately, you made it worse.  jsFiddle links are ok here, however, they're only ok here when the code is also shown in the OP.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because it's incomplete.  However, I made some changes that you should employ.  1)  I removed the inline JavaScript and call the slide functions from jQuery `click` handlers instead.  2)  I am using the `hide` method to remove the tooltips when the panel slides up.  However, the new problem you now must solve is; once you hide the tooltips and slide the panel back down, the tooltips refuse to come back.  I'll keep working at it.  Meanwhile, you need to put the relevant code within your OP. See: http://jsfiddle.net/k5w3tfsd/13/

Comment: Also `jQuery.validator.messages.required = ""` is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Ahh ok Sparky. I get you. Sorry. My bad. I now know for future how to correctly use this site. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, also please edit the question otherwise you will continue to get down-votes and the question will be closed as off-topic.  The point of SO is to also help future readers, which is not very effective when jsFiddle links go dead and no code can be seen.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With many thanks to the superb help of Louis over at Tooltipster I have a solution. The solution is upgrading to new version of tooltipster (currently working in dev branch of git jquery.tooltipster.js version 3.3.0), which gives a new feature: positionTracker.

Updated js fiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/k5w3tfsd/14/)

Enable the positionTracker and handle the errorPlacement from jquery validator:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// initialize tooltipster on text input elements
$('#yourForm input[type="text"]').tooltipster({
    theme: 'tooltipster-shadow',
    positionTracker: 'true',
    trigger: 'custom',
    onlyOne: false,
    position: 'right',
    animation: 'fall',
     positionTrackerCallback: function(){
         this.hide();
}


    });
});
```

and in the jquery validator function:

```
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    var lastError = $(element).data('lastError'),
        newError = $(error).text();

    $(element).data('lastError', newError);

    $(element).tooltipster('show');

    if (newError !== '' && newError !== lastError) {
        $(element).tooltipster('content', newError);
     $(element).tooltipster('show');
    }
},
success: function (label, element) {
    $(element).tooltipster('hide');

},
```

Comment: Ok, very nice that ToolTipster has a new feature that fixes your problem, however, please use the "edit" link on your answer to include the updated jsFiddle as well as edit your question to include the relevant code.  Thanks.